# Circular track problem with LCM

Tags: elementary-number-theory, gcd-and-lcm

I am not able to understand this question based on circular tracks:

> $A$ and $B$ start together from the same point on a circular track, and walk in the same direction until they both again arrive together at the starting point. $A$ completes one round in $224$ seconds and $B$ in $364$ seconds. How many times $A$ might have passed $B$?

Firstly I took the LCM of $224$ and $364$ in order to find the meeting point:
$2^5*7*13$. 
Then I divided this by $224$ to get the number of rounds taken by $A$ as $13$. Similarly I divided the LCM by $364$ to get the number of rounds taken by $B$ as $8$. So I think $A$ and $B$ must meet $8$ times, but the answer is $5$ i.e. difference between $13$ and $8$. Why? How can they meet just $5$ times? Can anyone explain?

Comment: 13 -8=5...........

Answer (score 2):

Lets make a table, of laps completed, and the floor of laps ahead (times when they must have passed):

$\begin{array}{|c|c|c|}
\hline
A & B& \lfloor{\text {laps ahead}}\rfloor \\ \hline
1 & \frac{8}{13}& 0\\ \hline
2 &  1\frac{3}{13}&0\\ \hline
3 &  1\frac{11}{13}&1\\ \hline
4 &  2\frac{6}{13}&1\\ \hline
5 &  3\frac{1}{13}&1\\ \hline
6 &  3\frac{9}{13}&2\\ \hline
7 &  4\frac{4}{13}&2\\ \hline
8 &  4\frac{12}{13}&3\\ \hline
9 &  5\frac{7}{13}&3\\ \hline
10 &  6\frac{2}{13}&3\\ \hline
11 &  6\frac{10}{13}&4\\ \hline
12 &  7\frac{5}{13}&4\\ \hline
13 &  8 & 5\\ \hline
\end{array}$

So, we can show, that the the number of laps ahead, hits 5 full laps when A did 13 laps, and B did 8 laps.

Answer (score 1):

They meet whenever the difference between their individual total distances traveled, measured in revolutions, is an integer.

The difference of their distances starts at $0$, is strictly increasing, and ends at $5$, hence they meet when the difference is one of the numbers $1,2,3,4,5$.

Answer (score 0):

A does 5 rounds more than B, so A will pass B 5 times